# Can't install Darts / llvmlite on Mac Python 3.8.9

Tags: python-3.x

Hello im having a real hard time installing darts in Python

Thanks in advance.

Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for llvmlite did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [16 lines of output]
running install
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
warnings.warn(
running build
got version from file /private/var/folders/m4/g2pdxhsd7dn2652ll8d9sz3c0000gn/T/pip-install-fza_0yk5/llvmlite_dc59eabdee5b435d8bd514c51e5c47db/llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.38.0', 'full': 'f0365b91ce1e1f74c68785c6d0067f32f89857d9'}
running build_ext
/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 /private/var/folders/m4/g2pdxhsd7dn2652ll8d9sz3c0000gn/T/pip-install-fza_0yk5/llvmlite_dc59eabdee5b435d8bd514c51e5c47db/ffi/build.py
LLVM version... Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/private/var/folders/m4/g2pdxhsd7dn2652ll8d9sz3c0000gn/T/pip-install-fza_0yk5/llvmlite_dc59eabdee5b435d8bd514c51e5c47db/ffi/build.py", line 220, in 
main()
File "/private/var/folders/m4/g2pdxhsd7dn2652ll8d9sz3c0000gn/T/pip-install-fza_0yk5/llvmlite_dc59eabdee5b435d8bd514c51e5c47db/ffi/build.py", line 214, in main
main_posix('osx', '.dylib')
File "/private/var/folders/m4/g2pdxhsd7dn2652ll8d9sz3c0000gn/T/pip-install-fza_0yk5/llvmlite_dc59eabdee5b435d8bd514c51e5c47db/ffi/build.py", line 134, in main_posix
raise RuntimeError(msg) from None
RuntimeError: Could not find a `llvm-config` binary. There are a number of reasons this could occur, please see: https://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin-guide/install.html#using-pip for help.
error: command '/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> llvmlite

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install darts in mac version 12.5.1 as follows:

My python version is different. But hoping this procedure works for you:

For your information below is my requirement.txt:

```html
protobuf==3.20.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
elasticsearch==7.13.0
elasticsearch-dsl==7.4.0
Flask==1.1.4
flask_restplus==0.13.0
Werkzeug==0.16.1
python-json-logger==2.0.2
ecs-logging==2.0.0
omegaconf==2.1.1
mock==4.0.3
nltk==3.6.7
PyJWT==2.4.0
pytest==6.2.5
requests==2.27.1
scikit-learn==1.0.2
pandas==1.3.5
pandasql==0.7.3
xlrd==2.0.1
colorlog==6.6.0
darts==0.15.0
psutil==5.9.1
decorator==5.1.1
zulu==2.0.0
```

**But for dart installation i was facing issue. I solved the issue by manually installing packages as follows:-**

```html
% python --version
Python 3.10.6
% pip install CMAKE
% pip install setuptools
% pip3 install gensim
% brew install lightgbm
% brew install cmake
% brew install libomp
% pip install httpstan
% pip install lightgbm
% pip install ipython
% pip install google-auth-oauthlib
% pip install filterpy
% pip install cmdstanpy
% pip install tensorboard
% pip install prophet
% pip install pmdarima
% pip install darts
% pip list | grep darts 
darts                                     0.21.0
```